# LG optimus 3D effect in portrait mode

Tags: android, 3d, landscape-portrait, optimus

I am working on LG optimus 3D mobile platform and it seems to me I can experience the depth of three dimensions in landscape mode but the effect is completely lost while the phone is in portrait. does anyone have any suggeston how to make that work on portrait mode as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the p920,   i'm afraid you (actually we cuz I have one too) are out of luck.  3d is landscape only.

Reference links :

- http://3dvision-blog.com/5798-testing-the-3d-capabilities-of-the-lg-optimus-3d-p920-smartphone/
- http://blog.gsmarena.com/htc-evo-3d-vs-lg-optimus-3d-taking-the-fight-to-another-dimension/